# AirPlay to computer

Tags: osx, windows-7, ios, cross-platform, airplay

I'm looking for a program that allows me to AirPlay my iPad (iOS 7) to my Mac (Snow Leopard) and my Windows PC (Win 7). So I want to be able to view my iPad's screen on my computers.

Requirements:

- No Jailbreak required
- Good streaming resolution
- Easy to set-up every time

I basically want to use my computers as an Apple TV but only for Airplay purposes.

It would be nice if this was free, but if it is cheap (under £15 - £20), I don't mind either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [X-Mirage](http://www.x-mirage.com/). It lets's you Airplay from any iOS or OSX devices to a computer running OSX or Windows. AT $16, it is well under your expected price range. There is no Jailbreak required. Once you start the app on your computer, an icon will appear on your  iPad's slide-up menu notifying you that an Airplay device is available in your local wireless network.

From experience, I have an app in my iPhone that let's me connect my guitar and play back the sound. X-Mirage played back my iPhone's screen to my Macbook and streamed the sound with very little sound delay over the wireless network.

Another instance where X-Mirage was useful, was when I had my Macbook connected to a projector. Other people in the meeting were able to play their own screen onto my screen without having to pass cables around.

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer. Especially: how does it fit the requirements of the OP? What makes it specifically recommendable? What are your experiences with it (if any)? Thanks in advance for your [edit]!

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the delay in accepting, I've been testing this with Reflector. X-Mirage does exactly what I want

Answer (score 3):

I know 2 really good programs that I used. The first is called [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/). The full version of Reflector cost $12.99. If you are unsure to buy it you can try it for free for 7 days. A nice feature of Reflector is that it can record your iDevice screen while air-playing. Reflector can be used for Mac and PC.

Another good one is [Air Server](http://www.airserver.com). Air Server, like Reflector, gives a 7 day trial. Air Server costs $14.99.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, but I found X-Mirage to be a better program that Reflector, but +1 for the good suggestions!